# Error in loops: replacement has length zero

Tags: r, loops

I have generated the following hypothetical data set:

```
    df<-data.frame(read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
ID Age Rel_1 Age_1 Rel_2 Age_2 Rel_3 Age_3
1   .    Self  12   Dad    40   Mom   38  
2   .     Dad   50  Mom    50   Self  22
3   .    Granddad  75  Mom  40   Self 15
4   .     Dad  45  Self 15   Mom 44   
5   .    Mom 50 Sister 18  Self 22
"))
```

Let each row represent a respondent that participated in a survey. Let columns Rel_1 through Age_3 represent members of the household of the survey respondent. ‘Rel’ stands for relationship. From this household roster, I want to retrieve the age of the survey respondent. The marker ‘Self’ does indicate it to me. Hence, if ‘Self’ is in Rel_2 then I know the age of the survey respondent is 12.

I figured out one way of doing it:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
print(i)
a<-which(df[i,]=="Self")+1 
df[i,2]<-df[i,a]
}
```

It works fine.

However, now let us incorporate a mistake in the data collected.  I change ‘Self’ in row 3 into ‘Son’. Some minor mistakes that could have happened during data collection.

```
df<-data.frame(read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
ID Age Rel_1 Age_1 Rel_2 Age_2 Rel_3 Age_3
1   .    Self  12   Dad    40   Mom   38  
2   .     Dad   50  Mom    50   Self  22
3   .    Granddad  75  Mom  40   Son 15
4   .     Dad  45  Self 15   Mom 44   
5   .    Mom 50 Sister 18  Self 22
"))
```

If I now run my previous code to extract the information on age. I get the following error message:

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, 2, value = list()) : replacement has length zero

In fact, it only extract the information on age until row 2. It does not seem to skip row 3 and again extract the information on age in row 4 and 5.

Who has some ideas what went wrong and what can I do to ‘skip’ row 3 where ‘Self’ has not specified?

Thanks

Comment: Basically I wonder what can be done that not every mistake like the one mentioned makes the loop stop. I am currently work with a data set of around 3000 data points. applying the loop I wrote just helps me to fill the first couple of hundred entries.

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle mistakes on the fly, like:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
        print(i)
        a<-which(df[i,]=="Self")+1 
        if(length(a)>0)
           df[i,2]<-df[i,a]
}
```

Or you can pre-process to remove lines with mistakes at first.

Comment: makes perfect sense and generates the results I want! Thanks so much!